# help needed restructuring a php array

Tags: php, arrays

I was wondering if anyone could help me restructure a predefined php array. The output of my current array is:

```
Array
(
    [71-ctns] => 1
    [71-units] => 1
    [308-units] => 1
    [305-ctns] => 1
    [306-units] => 2
)
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
Array
(
    [71] => Array
        (
            [ctns] => 1
            [units] => 1
        )
    [308] => Array
        (
            [units] => 1
        )

    [305] => Array
        (
            [ctns] => 1
        )
    [306] => Array
        (
            [units] => 2
        )
)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
$merged = array();
foreach($a as $k=>$v){
    $t = explode('-',$k);
    $id = intval($t[0]);
    if(!array_key_exists($id, $merged))
        $merged[$id] = array();
    $merged[$id][$t[1]] = $v;
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry you should use explode instead of split.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to loop (note: array_map can also work, but this example is more explicit):

```
$fin = array();
foreach( $complex as $item => $val ) 
{
    $pieces = explode('-', $item);
    $fin[$pieces[0]] = isset($fin[$pieces[0]])?:array();
    $fin[$pieces[0]][$pieces[1]] = $val;
}
```

Comment: I think you want `$fin[$pieces[0]][$pieces[1]] = $val;`

Answer (score 1):

Find below code to restructure a predefined php array

```
<?php
$newArray=array();
$result = array("71-ctns"=>1,"71-units"=>1,"308-ctns"=>1,"308-units"=>1,"305-units"=>1,"306-units"=>2);
if(is_array($result) && count($result)>0) {
    foreach($result as $key=>$val) {
        $getKeyArray = explode("-",$key);
        $newArray[$getKeyArray[0]][$getKeyArray[1]] =$val;      
    }
}
print"<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
?>
```